# How to block access to quartz monitor in grails application

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have the quartz monitor plugin in a grails facebook app.  All the controllers in the main app use authentication with facebook.  How can I configure the plugin for quartz monitor so that it cannot be accessed by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring security plugin to do auth stuff, then you can create separate Role, for example ROLE_QUARTZ_USER, and then secure access to quartz controller by adding following annotation to its methods:

```
 @Secured(['ROLE_QUARTZ_USER'])
```

Since FaceBook users wont have this role, Spring Security will deny access for them.

Comment: I'm not using spring security, since for the rest of the app there is no need.

Comment: You have other way to distinguish users, right? Then just add some check to quartz monitor controller methods.

Comment: I got spring security installed in my app but i cant access the QuartzController dues to plugin source not found. Did some one know why could be that happening. I edited plugins before but quartz and quartz-monitor don't let me to expand them.

Comment: @kenota you say "secure access to quartz controller" - what about quartz job? I have a job allowed to be executed manually, but we want to limit that to a role. I am testing that and it looks it doesn't work with quartz job